# Does the depletion region sustain after a forward bias greater than knee voltage has been Applied to a PN junction diode?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

The depletion region reduces as the forward bias is increased. Does at any point it reach zero or negligible length?
Knee voltage of a diode is defined as the minimum amount of forward bias required for the diode to show significant conduction. It denotes the potential barrier created across the depletion region via accumulation of charges, i.e. negative charges on P side, and positive on N side

Comment: This question is not well posed because it doesn't give any information about the considered physical object. How is the "knee voltage" defined?

Comment: Of course it does, once the Fermi levels come in to alignment.

Comment: I have applied a bias. How can the fermi level be aligned in external bias? My question is whether external bias can make depletion region go zero,  once the external bias exceeds the knee voltage

Comment: When the external forward bias equals the built-in potential, what do you call that?

Answer (score 1):

The "knee voltage" is a rather arbitrary concept sometimes taken as the voltage where the current is 1mA. There is no "knee" in an exponentially increasing function like the ideal pn-junction I-V characteristic. By applying a large enough forward voltage that overcomes the built in voltage, you can make the depletion zone disappear. This voltage has nothing to do with the mentioned "knee voltage". The depletion zone disappears at the latest when your applied forward voltage times elementary charge corresponds to the band gap energy. At such large forward voltages the simple Shockley theory for the exponential I-V characteristics doesn't hold anymore.